# Apache2 server restart failed - Tried multiple options

Tags: apache, openproject

I tried to restart failed and i tried multiple options, Yet i could not able to restart the apache2.
Below links i have tried for the problems and yet i could not able to restart.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n

https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n/256018

i am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and i am hosting the openproject software.

i added the lines as they said. Yet my apache server is not starting.

my ipaddress is 192.168.1.146 (localhost) to browse openproject

Yesterday it was working and i could able to open the project from other computers.
http://192.168.1.146 
it will navigate to the index page of the openproject.

awaiting your reply.

Comment: Please, add details about errors you get during apache restart.

Comment: root@OpenProject:/home/craftsilicon# sudo service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
--

Comment: For the above error, i tried the steps which explained in the forum and other places. Still i could not able to restart the apache2 server.

Comment: @vivekrajagopalan, add in your question the output of commands `systemctl status apache2.service` and `journalctl -xe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:-
netstat -ltnp | grep :80
I found that nginx is running.
So i done sudo apt-get purge nginx

sudo kill -9 982

sudo service nginx stop

sudo service apache2 start

Answer (score 0):

> craftsilicon@OpenProject:~$ systemctl status apache2.service
>   apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
>              └─apache2-systemd.conf    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-02-03 15:23:49 IST; 13s ago   Process: 3461
>   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILU
>
> Feb 03 15:23:49 OpenProject apachectl[3461]: [Mon Feb 03
>   15:23:49.816448 2020] [ Feb 03 15:23:49 OpenProject apachectl[3461]:
>   (98)Address already in use: AH00072 Feb 03 15:23:49 OpenProject
>   apachectl[3461]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072 Feb 03 15:23:49
>   OpenProject apachectl[3461]: no listening sockets available, shu Feb
>   03 15:23:49 OpenProject apachectl[3461]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
>   Feb 03 15:23:49 OpenProject apachectl[3461]: Action 'start' failed.
>   Feb 03 15:23:49 OpenProject apachectl[3461]: The Apache error log may
>   have more  Feb 03 15:23:49 OpenProject systemd[1]: apache2.service:
>   Control process exited, Feb 03 15:23:49 OpenProject systemd[1]:
>   apache2.service: Failed with result 'exi Feb 03 15:23:49 OpenProject
>   systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
>
> craftsilicon@OpenProject:~$ journalctl -xe
>
> -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up. Feb 03 15:24:51 OpenProject systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary
>   Directories.
>   -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
>
> ### -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
>
> -- The start-up result is RESULT. Feb 03 15:25:01 OpenProject CRON[3580]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by
>   (uid=0 Feb 03 15:25:01 OpenProject CRON[3583]: (root) CMD (command -v
>   debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1  Feb 03 15:25:01 OpenProject
>   CRON[3580]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root Feb
>   03 15:30:57 OpenProject systemd-resolved[606]: Using degraded feature
>   set (UDP) for DNS server 4.2 Feb 03 15:32:21 OpenProject
>   libreoffice-writer.desktop[3668]: javaldx: Could not find a Java
>   Runtime E Feb 03 15:32:21 OpenProject
>   libreoffice-writer.desktop[3668]: Please ensure that a JVM and the
>   package Feb 03 15:32:21 OpenProject libreoffice-writer.desktop[3668]:
>   is installed. Feb 03 15:32:21 OpenProject
>   libreoffice-writer.desktop[3668]: If it is already installed then try
>   remo Feb 03 15:32:21 OpenProject libreoffice-writer.desktop[3668]:
>   Warning: failed to read path from javald Feb 03 15:32:24 OpenProject
>   audit[3687]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open"
>   profile="libreoffice- Feb 03 15:32:24 OpenProject audit[3687]: AVC
>   apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="libreoffice- Feb 03
>   15:32:24 OpenProject kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 32 callbacks
>   suppressed Feb 03 15:32:24 OpenProject kernel: audit: type=1400
>   audit(1580724144.128:44): apparmor="ALLOWED" oper Feb 03 15:32:24
>   OpenProject kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1580724144.128:45):
>   apparmor="ALLOWED" oper lines 3213-3235/3235 (END)